# Can´t get logical to report true

Tags: netlogo

I can´t seem to get a logical condition that I expect to report true, to actually report true. I have several logicals connected by "and", each of which reports true by itself, yet when connected Im getting false. I must have an error in my code, but cannot seem to locate it. Any help would be great.

Below is the relevant code:

```
globals [ 
      GF-Threshold
      GF-Probablility]

turtles own [ GF+?]

patches own [ GF ]

to setup [ 
     ask patches [ set GF 30]
     ask turtles [ set GF+? false]
     set GF-threshold 20
     set GF-Probability .9

to go [ 
     ask turtles [ check phenotype ]

to check phenotype 
     [ if GF+? = false and GF > GF-threshold and random-float 1 < GF-Probability [ set GF+? true]
```

I have a monitor for number of turtles with GF+? = true. The monitor shows 0 when I use the above code. But I expect that the logical should be reporting true, thus the monitor would show a value greater than 0. I tried each of the logicals on their own, and the monitor shows a non-zero value when I do so. Is there something you see wrong with my code? I also tried using patch-here, thinking that maybe the problem was communication between the patch and turtle.

```
  to check phenotype 
     [ if GF+? = false and [GF] of patch-here > GF-threshold and random-float 1 < GF-Probability [ set GF+? true]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no problems with the code. This is what I used (I fixed the syntax so it would run, I assume you deleted some lines when creating the example code). This means there are two possibilities. The first is that you didn't create any turtles (I had to add that line in the setup).

```
globals [ 
      GF-Threshold
      GF-Probability]

turtles-own [ GF+?]

patches-own [ GF ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 50 
     ask patches [ set GF 30]
     ask turtles [ set GF+? false]
     set GF-threshold 20
     set GF-Probability .9
end

to go
  ask turtles [ check-phenotype ]
end

to check-phenotype 
     if GF+? = false and GF > GF-threshold and random-float 1 < GF-Probability
       [ set GF+? true]
end
```

The second is that your monitor code is the problem. Here is the code I used.

```
count turtles with [GF+? = true]
```

Just an extra note, I used your syntax to check whether a boolean (GF+?) was true or false. You can also do `if GF+?` instead of `if GF+? = true` and similarly `if not GF+?` instead of `if GF+? = false`.

Comment: Indeed the syntax of the code was not correct. Thank you for your example code. I see that this code indeed works by itself, yet when I put it into the model it does not. I must have something else going on. Strangely if I use `if GF+? != true`in place of `if GF+? = false` then I can get the monitor to respond as I am expecting. This seems very strange to me. Also, I tried using your example with `if not GF+?`but was given an error saying "expected a T/F but got the number zero". Perhaps this has something to do with what I am seeing? I´m using a numeric when I think Im using a Boolean? Thanks

Comment: observador> show count turtles with [GF+? = false]
    observer: 0
    observador> show count turtles with [GF+? != true]
    observer: 320

Comment: The above commands were given in the command window following setup procedures. I dont understand how these could give different answers.

Comment: I just figured it out. I was setting the GF+? to false before the turtles were created in the setup procedure. Your comment helped me to figure this out. Thank you.